# change height of buttons in jquery mobile 1.4, best practices

Tags: jquery-mobile

With JQM 1.3 the best practice to change a button's height was :

```
#containerdivID .ui-btn {
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

is it still right for JQM 1.4...I mean the buttons are weird, there is a kind a inner margin around them :

[image]

Here's my html :

```
  <div id="expShortButtonsStart">
                <button id="ExpShortGotoapp" class="ui-btn-b ui-icon-logo ui-btn-icon-right">Start</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the button is into a div container, you need to remove the top and bottom padding:

```
#expShortButtonsStart .ui-btn {
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Without div container, the old way works well :

```
#buttonid.ui-btn {
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't it weird to have to force css padding: 0; and margin:0; on every button ? Why JQM puts a weird margin around the buttons like this ?

Comment: it seems to be only due to the container div I was adding for JQM 1.3

Comment: I edited your answer too quickly, apparently we are both wrong, event with padding:0 the button is still weird...

Comment: @Louis, you've lost me. Here is a fiddle with my CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7827m/. Can you edit it to reproduce your problem, then click update and then post the new URL in the next comment so I can see the issue?

Comment: I lost myself....I tried to reproduce the bug in the jsfiddle...but I can't, I have simplified my html, but the jsfiddle doesn't show the same thing...

Comment: I just discorvered that the big margins I see are only there when I land on the page, if I refresh the page, they disappear....could it be a JS problem ?

Comment: @Louis, without seeing your code and markup it is hard to say what might be the problem...

Comment: I know ! I don't know how to proceed... maybe when the app is released it'll be easier.