# weird behavior in Jquery mobile 1.4 with buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile

As mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068267/change-height-of-buttons-in-jquery-mobile-1-4-best-practices) I had issues changing the height of buttons in JQM 1.4.
I found what triggers it :

HTML:

```
<button id="ExpShortHowItWorksInfo" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-question ui-btn-icon-right" >Check how it works in details</button>
```

With this, the buttons has a different markup and there's a div containing the button (.ui-btn-inline is not accounted for)  :

```
$('#ExpShortHowItWorksInfo').button().on("tap", function() {
        $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#faq-page", { transition: "fade" });
    });
```

Whereas with this, there is no issue (wihtout `button()`) :

```
$('#ExpShortHowItWorksInfo').on("tap", function() {
            $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#faq-page", { transition: "fade" });
        });
```

Comment: Use `a` not `button`, or add `data-role="none"` to `button`.

Comment: @Omar is using button not a good practice ? Is the usage of button() recommanded/useful or not ?

Comment: @Omar, thanks I didn't see the duplicate. Should I delete the question then ?